# GeoServer layer group problem

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I seem to be having a problem previewing a layer group in GeoServer.  I have three shapefiles that I converted from a DXF file and I can preview each successfully, however when I try to preview the layer group nothing appears apart from the OpenLayers border and nav controls.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Generate Bounds button (assuming all your data is in the same projection and area of interest.)

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/data/layergroups.html

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. Make sure the 3 shape files are in the same projection if once you're bounds are calculated you still have the same problem.

Comment: Also be sure to keep the raster or the basemap is on top in your group layer as shown in the above image